# Data Migration from different sources and schema to MS SQL server

Tags: migration, etl

We are government organisation and receiving data from different stakeholders usually data is not in single for format some like CSV, Excel, database views Also schema is not same always for source data. Some data is continuous streaming of data in CSV format at FTP folders. Is there any software that will automate this all work.

Comment: In SSIS creating these ETL pipelines is not easy appreciate if we can have some software doing it

Answer (score 0):

This is where ETL tools comes into picture. Microsoft has SSIS(SQL Server Integration Services) which provides connectors to these systems like another SQL Server or CSV Files or Excel or a shared location where the data files are getting dumped. You might have to design the ETL pipeline to get all the data into your SQL Server database.
[SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017)